# if statement based on Label tekst

Tags: jquery

How do i trigger a function based on label text

```
<label>This Text</label>

if (label.text === "This Text") {
 alert(hi);
}
```

Comment: Please, be more specific. WHat is "label" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what is `label`?  Does it have a `text` property?  If you've identified the `<label>` element using a jQuery selector, you can get the text therein with [the `text()` function](http://api.jquery.com/text/).  Something like this:

```
<label>This Text</label>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var label = $('label');
    if (label.text() === 'This Text') {
        alert('hi');
    }
</script>
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rQfFB/).

Comment: This may sound cliché but... any particular reason for the down-vote?

Comment: thanks this works (Y) don't know why downvoting it idiots

Comment: @John: That's why I hesitated to ask.  Votes are anonymous and should never be taken personally.  But I'm genuinely interested in improving the answer if somebody has a constructive suggestion.  Either way, glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in several ways

```
 $("label").text();

 document.getElementsByTagName('label')[0].firstChild.data
```

It can also be done by assigning class or id to label and then accessing it as

```
  $("#label").text();
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kf65r/)